# Java API for Prime Number and Factorization

Tags: java, api, primes, factorization

I am looking for Java API for fast primality testing and factorization of Big Numbers. Any pointer would be very helpful to me.

### Update

The resources I found are:

- [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) - doesn't have factorization
- [Primes](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/primes/Primes.html) - deals with integer
- [LargeInteger](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/number/LargeInteger.html) - doesn't have factorization

I am looking forward to an API which uses [Elliptic Curve Factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic_curve_factorization) or [Quadratic Sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve).

Another resource: [Factorization using the Elliptic Curve Method](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM).

Limit: Number with 10000 digit.

Comment: Factoring the product of two large primes is notoriously hard, how big are the factors?

Comment: @flup number upto 10000 digit. Also see my update.

Comment: The second resource you are linking has a zip with java sources.

Comment: @flup I already have that. It would be very hard refactoring the code to get what I want.

Comment: Ummm.... You do know that factoring a 10000-digit number, unless it only consists of very small factors, is very far beyond the realm of possibility, don't you? The biggest semi-prime that has been factored to date is only a few hundred digits.

Comment: +1 @user448810 if it doesn't get factorize then its a prime. what I want is to is to determine the primality and if it is composite then its factors.

Comment: @TapasBose: You can test primality with Miller-Rabin or Baillie-Wagstaff. See my [essay](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) for Miller-Rabin or my [blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2013/03/01/baillie-wagstaff-pseudoprimality-tester/) for Baillie-Wagstaff. I also have elliptic curve and quadratic sieve implementations at my blog.

Comment: @user448810 thank you. I will definitely read them.

Comment: https://algorithmia.com/algorithms/microprediction/IsPrime

Comment: @PeterCotton thanks for pointing out this number theory library from SymPy. The code in the link given by you uses [isprime](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html#sympy.ntheory.primetest.isprime).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Commons Math. You can find lib [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) API [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/). The class that would be interesting for you is [Primes](https://github.com/apache/commons-math/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math4/primes/Primes.java).

Comment: I have looked http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/primes/Primes.html it deals with integer.

Answer (score 0):

I have used sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm implemented in Java

```js
public static ArrayList<Integer> primeNumbers(int end) {
  // generate array of number from 2 to end
  // generate flag array of same size
  // this numbers are inclusive
  int eff = 0;
  ArrayList<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  if (end < 2) {
   return factors;
  }
  if (end == 2) {
   factors.add(2);
   return factors;
  }
  int numbers[] = new int[end - 1];
  boolean flags[] = new boolean[end - 1];
  int count = 2;
  // lets reset all numbers
  for (int i = 0; i < end - 1; i++) {
   numbers[i] = count;
   flags[i] = true;
   count++;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < end - 1; i++) {
   if (flags[i]) {
    factors.add(numbers[i]);
    int loop = 2;
    for (long j = numbers[i] * loop; j <= end; j = numbers[i]
      * loop, loop++) {
     flags[(int) (j - 2)] = false;
     eff++;
    }
   }
  }
  // System.out.println(eff);
  return factors;
 }
```

This will give you all prime numbers below given number i.e. 
listOfPrime {2,3,5,7} = primeNumbers(10);
we can use the same array to check divisibility

```js
public static ArrayList < Integer > getPrimeFactors(int n) {
  ArrayList < Integer > primeNumbers = primeNumbers((n / 2) + 1);
  ArrayList < Integer > removal = new ArrayList < Integer > ();
  for (int i = 0; i < primeNumbers.size(); i++) {
    if (n % primeNumbers.get(i) != 0) {
      removal.add(primeNumbers.get(i));
    }
  }
  primeNumbers.removeAll(removal);
  return primeNumbers;
}
```